# “500 error” in file-upload for REST API using C# client

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I have to upload a file to third party server using REST API. I have bare minimum document is available for that REST method.
When I use Postman to call the service, it works. Part of the generated code in Postman for C#  is like this :

```
var client = new RestClient("<URL>");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "6cb9f00b-e1ac-f8d8-b5d6-eeb67b06ae6a");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic cm9vdDpIaXRhY2hpQDEy");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--   -011000010111000001101001");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=-- -011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-  Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"[object Object]\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--",     ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The following code written in Python also works –

```
vroAuth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("<username>","<Password> ")
url =  <url>
files = {"file":open("<absolute file path on client machine>",'rb')}
response_output = requests.post(url, auth=vroAuth,files=files, verify=False)
```

Based on these two code snippets ,I tried to write client code in C# like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(restBaseUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
ServicePoint sp = request.ServicePoint;
var fl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 60 * 60 * 1000;
request.Accept = "application/json"; 
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
String headerInfo = "file; filename=" + fileName;              
request.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = headerInfo;
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
using (var strm = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
   {
         file.CopyTo(strm);
   }
}
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

There , I am getting “error 500 – Internal server error”. Unfortunately, there is no information in the header returned from the server. If I try different Content Type for request ( for example - "application/octet-stream";, I am getting error 415 – Media type not supported). All I know is “file” is one of the parameters with Data type as “File”. Any suggestion, how can I proceed to resolve the issue ?

Comment: What does your actual content look like?  Based on the error, the server is probably throwing an error because you are sending it data that it cannot understand

Comment: The file is a DAR file. I used the same file while calling the REST API by Postman or Python.You are right. The way I am sending the data - is not according  the format - which the server is expecting.

Comment: The easiest way is to use something like Fiddler to see what is being sent when you do it with c# code vs Postman or Python.